# Grid view displaying incorrect values after inserting a record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a form in a `aspx` page. In the form I have a drop down list for categories. The drop down list values must be accessed from a database table. So I created a `Category` and `Products` table in SQL database with a column called `c_id` and `c_name` and manually entered 10 values.

Now I have written some code to access and its working fine but I want this drop down to display in ascending order, so in sql query I have taken `order by c_name asc`. In dropdown am getting ascending order, but the problem is, that the selected dropdownlist value is showing wrongly in grid view after inserting record into `Products` table. It is not taking `c_id`, it is taking default 1 to 10. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Please show us the code that you have written so we can understand better what your problem is.

Comment: where is the code ??

Comment: Go ahead and add the code you currently have and I would be happy to help you out.

Comment: Thank u for ur response guys... problem resolved , I have done some changes.Its working as expected..Thank u all